# Google Maps InfoWindow anchor point moving window

Tags: api, position, maps, infowindow, pan

I'm trying to create anchor tags inside the Google Maps InfoWindow that jump down further into the InfoWindow. When I click on an anchor point link in my InfoWindows, it does go down to the content within the InfoWindow. The problem is that the entire InfoWindow moves up to the top of the page when I click a link.

Is there any way to keep the InfoWindow from moving? I don't want to use   disableAutoPan: true because I do like that it moves the InfoWindow initially. I just don't want it to move upon the anchor hyperlink click.

Right now it looks like:

```
var locations = [];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 3,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-1, 35),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    disableDefaultUI: true
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 500
  });

  var marker, i;

  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
      map: map
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
      return function() {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i));
  }
```